# $3$ times a number, plus $4$, is equal to $10$

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

I was helping my brother with his math homework and there was this question:

$3$ times a number, plus $4$, is equal to $10$. What is that number?

My first thought was that $3x+4 = 10$ and then, solve for $x$. But then, my brother told me maybe it’s $3(x+4)=10$. Now I’m confused too. Which one is right? I think it’s the former given that “plus $4$” was in-between commas but I’m not sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would read it the way you did, but of course mathematical phrasing in English is always going to be ambiguous.  Helps to note that your way comes out an integer, and the other does not.

Comment: Compare "3 times a number, plus 4" with "3 times, a number plus 4".

Comment: When I speak aloud with potentially ambiguous statements like this, I add exaggerated pauses and inflections in my voice to try to convey where the implied parentheses are.  E.g. "Three times (*long break*)  (*speaking quickly*) a number plus four (*break again*)..."  For written English, that is much harder to do.  I would then maybe include the phrase "the result of" if I want to imply parentheses.  "Three times the result of a number plus four..."  Without these implied parentheses, I would interpret it as one would with order of operations.

Comment: Not sure why this question is being downvoted: the mathematical content may be light, but the problem is clearly and concisely explained.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Am not saying that it should be downvoted, but it could be because it is about language and not mathematics. There is no real answer to this question other than language can be anbiguous and sometimes is on purpose to annoy people.

Comment: If nothing else is stated (what kind of number it is), afaik standard convention is to use natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ (or integers) for counting hence, $3x+4=10$ would be the correct one. If the homework says its a real number $\mathbb{R}$ then the latter is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is as you typed it, the comma after number indicates you are expected to read it as $3x+4=10$.  You multiply the number by $3$, pause, and add $4$.  It would be hard to express $3(x+4)=10$  without restructuring the sentence.

The language used indicates this is a low level class.  The fact that $3x+4=10$ results in a whole number for $x$ while $3(x+4)=10$ does not argues strongly for $3x+4=10$ being the intended interpretation.

Comment: " It would be hard to express 3(x+4)=10 without restructuring the sentence."   It could be expressed (awkwardly) as "three, times a number plus four, is equal to ten" or (grammatically incorrect but contextually clear) as "three times, a number plus four, is equal to ten".  I'd avoid doing so but I think it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

THe important thing is that your brother understands the idea that three times (a  number plus four, and (three times a number) plus four, are different concepts and will have different results.

After that it's not a matter of which is right but how well did the text express it and what was the text's intent.  In other words it's not a matter of math but of language.

If the question were indeed written as "3 times a number, plus 4, is equal to 10" then the commas and the embedded clause makes it clear that they mean $(3x) + 4 = 10$.

I suppose to express $3(x+4)= 10$ with the same word structure one could write "3, times a number plus 4, is equal to 10" but that's a little awkward.  I'd probably say something more explicit such as "3 times the sum of a number plus four, is equal to 10".

A sentence without commas,  "3 times a number plus 4 is equal to 10", is ambiguous but I think it is natural to hear think left to right:  $3x + 4 = 10$.  Also the conventions of math is to simply list as you hear the  "3" (that's $3$) "times" (that's $\cdot $) "a number" (that's $x$) "plus" (that's $+$) "4" (that's $4$) "is equal to" (that's $=$) "ten" (that's $10$) so it is $3\cdot x + 4 = 10$.

Likewise "3 plus a number times 4 is equal to 10" without commas is most likely to be interpreted as $3+x\cdot 4 = 10$.  And conventions of mathematics and order of operations determine the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly the problem is intended to be $3x+4=10$.

But your brother has made an important discovery. Until the sixteenth century, all mathematical textbooks would write out such problems in words, like "3 times a number, plus 4, is equal to 10". As your and your brother have discovered, this can be difficult to interpret correctly, and certainly takes up a lot of space. If simply writing down a mathematical equation is difficult and time consuming and error prone then it makes you less likely to spend time working out how to solve the equation. And if you do find a method of solving a particular type of equation then it is much harder to explain your method to other people.

The adoption of standard mathematical symbols such as $+$ and $=$ and the use of letters like $x$ to stand for unknown quantities was a big step forwards in the development of modern mathematics.